# How to fix this error. Osmand android app routing.xml file error

Tags: android, android-maps, osmand

how to fix this error. I think to rounting.xml file mistake directory. where to copy routing.xml file.

parseDefault in return "null". now copied to Android/Data/net.osmand/files/routing/routing.xml

[image]

how to fix this error. I think to rounting.xml file mistake directory. where to copy routing.xml file.